# Permalink structure when the website has two blogs

Tags: php, wordpress, url, permalinks

My website has two blogs. Imagine that their url are mydomain.com/blog1 and mydomain.com/blog2.

I'd like to have post url such as:

- mydomain.com/blog1/sample-post-from-blog1
- mydomain.com/blog2/sample-post-from-blog2

Posts from both blogs are under 'Post' Wordpress section and I think of differentiating them by tags or categories 'blog1' and 'blog2', although I'm not sure about what's the best practice.

So I'm kind of lost. Anyone has a clue about it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can make it by making two separate custom post types for for both of the blogs. do not use default posts for your first blog.

Comment: Thanks @Rajkumar. That's in fact a solution. The thing is that my first blog already exists and it has ~150 posts. Should I create two separate custom post types and migrate my first blog from default posts to the new one? Would I be penalized in terms of SEO, although I keep the same url for the first blog posts?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this:

- I kept blog1 posts within default WP posts
- For blog1 posts I defined a custom structure for permalinks: /blog/%postname%/
- I created a custom post type for blog2 posts
- To avoid the prefix '/blog/' to be applied to blog2 posts, I changed its 'with_front' property to 'false' ([ref](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/231645/get-posts-for-custom-post-type-with-wp-query))
- Using qTranslate Slug plugin, I set '/blog2-name/' as a slug for this new custom post type.